# Identical arrays in .NET API endpoint response

Tags: c#, .net

Let's take for example this endpoint I have,

```
[HttpGet("persons/{personId:guid}/profile/organizations/coordinates")]
public async Task<Result<List<ProfileCoordinateViewModel>>> GetProfileCoordinates(Guid personId)
{
    try
    {
        var coordinates = await _profileCoordinateService.GetProfileCoordinates(personId);

        var result = new List<ProfileCoordinateViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in coordinates)
        {
            result.Add(ProfileCoordinateViewModel.FromDomainObj(item));
        }

        return Result.Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Result.Fail("Something went wrong: ")
            .WithError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

For the result that is being returned I am using `FluentResults`. It returns the following response:

```json
{
  "valueOrDefault": [
    {
      "email1": "string@test.be",
      "email1IsPublic": false,
      "email2": null,
      "email2IsPublic": false,
      "fax": null,
      "faxIsPublic": false,
      "mobile": null,
      "mobileIsPublic": false,
      "palaceBox": null,
      "palaceBoxIsPublic": false,
      "phone": null,
      "phoneIsPublic": false
    }
  ],
  "value": [
    {
      "email1": "string@test.be",
      "email1IsPublic": false,
      "email2": null,
      "email2IsPublic": false,
      "fax": null,
      "faxIsPublic": false,
      "mobile": null,
      "mobileIsPublic": false,
      "palaceBox": null,
      "palaceBoxIsPublic": false,
      "phone": null,
      "phoneIsPublic": false
    }
  ],
  "isFailed": false,
  "isSuccess": true,
  "reasons": [],
  "errors": [],
  "successes": []
}
```

I want the response to only contain `isSuccess`/`isFailed` (depending on which is true) and a single result; not both the value and `valueOrDefault` objects. I'm guessing it has to do with `FluentResults` because my repository and service return correctly. Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a long , but I will give a detailed explanation. And I think it will work for you in the end. In Order to do this ,Let's create a 2 interface

1. IResult => If you want to return just Success or Message
2. IDataResult=>If you want to return Success or Message with data

   ```
   public interface IResult
   {

   public bool Success { get; }
   public string Message { get;}

   }
   ```

This is IDataResult

```
   public  interface IDataResult< out T>:IResult
{
    T Data { get; }
}
```

We are creating a class which is going to abstract IResult;

```
public class Result : IResult
{
    public Result(bool success)
    {
        Success=success;    
    }

    public Result(bool success,string message):this(success)
    {
       
        Message=message;
    }
    public bool Success { get ; }
    public string Message { get ; }
}
```

}

Ok now if we want to return just message or success,use SuccessResult class

```
  public  class SuccessResult:Result
  {
  public SuccessResult():base(true)
  {

  }

  public SuccessResult(string message) : base(true,message)
  {

  }
  }
```

if you want to return just message or success also with data use SuccessDataResult class

```
    public class SuccessDataResult<T> : DataResult<T>
{
    public SuccessDataResult(T data) : base(data, true)
    {

    }

    public SuccessDataResult(T data,string message) : base(data, true,message)
    {

    }


  
}
```

in Your business or Service Layer you can do like this ;
if I want to return just Message or Success:

```
        public Result Add(Category category)
    {
        _categoryDal.Add(category);

        return new Result(true, "A new Record Has Added");
    }
```

If I need to return a data with Success or message,you can use like this ;

```
        public IDataResult<Category> Get(int id)
    {
        return new SuccessDataResult<Category>(_categoryDal.Get(a => a.Id 
         == id),Messages.Get_Record);
    }
```

Thanks to this structure result always return true,false,message or data. By the way you can create ErrorResult,ErrorDataResult like SuccessResult. The structure will provide this.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public IActionResult Add(Category category)
    {
        var result = _categoryService.Add(category);

        if (result.Success)
        {

            return Ok(result);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Message);
    }
```